# Spring Boot REST API: Exposing (or not) associated entities in JSON

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I am building a Spring Boot based application to expose a JSON REST API.
In this application I have a 1-to-many relationship: one Order has multiple Items (and one Item belongs to exactly one Order).
I would like to have the following 4 API endpoints:

- GET all Orders: In this case I just want the Order itself - so excluding the associated Items
- GET a single Order: get the Order itself including the associated Items
- GET single Item: get a single Item including the Order it belongs to (here it does not matter whether just the ID (=primary key) of the order is included or the whole order itself
- GET all Items: the all the items; the associated Order is not necessary - but it also would not hurt.

Unfortunately I am a bit lost on how to model my associations and/or controller methods that expose the API endpoints.
Do you have some hints for me?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: GET /orders;
GET /orders/{id}   remember to do join fetch in service (or fetchType.Eager);
GET /items; 
GET /orders/{id}/items if You want to have items for particular order;
GET /items/{id}  single item;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first choice should always be to resort to Software Design Patterns. When developing applications which may require remote connections (or not), there is one that should be implemented in your rest api: [Data Transfer Object](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html).

Having into account you are developing under Java/Spring Framework, you should take a look at [modelmapper](http://modelmapper.org/) library and to [this guide](http://www.baeldung.com/entity-to-and-from-dto-for-a-java-spring-application).

I have successfully done the same task in my rest api.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a better method of doing that, but my approach would be to model and fetch the relations using Hibernate, but in a lazy manner (https://howtoprogramwithjava.com/hibernate-eager-vs-lazy-fetch-type/).

In your controller, you do not return the entity but a DTO class that might be pretty similar to your entity. That DTO is created by some mapper component that provides the logic of including or not including associated items, etc.